# Hibernate Merge Issue with joined column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am using java 8 with JPA2/Hibernate5 and mySql.

```
+--------+    +----------------+    +------------+ 
| Rating |    | Rating_Person  |    | Person     |
+--------+    +----------------+    +------------+ 
| ID     |    | RAT_ID         |    | ID         |
| PERSON |    | PER_ID         |    | USERNAME   | 
+--------+    +----------------+    +------------+
```

I have an entity `RATING` that has a `PERSON` object. When I try `merge` the `RATING`, it gets an error because there is already a `PERSON` in the database with a unique column value `USERNAME`.

```
entityManager.merge(rating);
```

I get the following error:

> Duplicate entry 'richardmarais' for key 'USERNAME_UNIQUE'

It looks like I need to not try and add a new `PERSON`. I don't need to even update the `PERSON`.

I tried updating my code to:

```
    Person person = rating.getPerson();
    Person dbPerson = personService.findByUserName(person.getUserName());
    if (dbPerson != null) {
        rating.setPerson(dbPerson);
    }
    entityManager.merge(rating);
```

But I get:

> There was an error trying to save Rating [null]. Multiple
>   representations of the same entity [com.jobs.spring.domain.Person#8]
>   are being merged. Detached: [com.jobs.spring.domain.Person@30466c01];
>   Managed: [com.jobs.spring.domain.Person@7c2ba1a2]

Can anyone please advise me how I can add a new `RATING` without adding a new `PERSON`?

I try add the `@Column` annotation on the `PERSON` object to tell it not to add a new `PERSON`.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable
(
    name="rating_person",
    joinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="RAT_ID", referencedColumnName="ID") },
    inverseJoinColumns={ @JoinColumn(name="PER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID") }
)
@Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Person person;
```

But then on start up I get.

> @Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property:
>   com.jobs.spring.domain.Rating.person

When I read the `RATING` entity I do need to get the associated `PERSON` though.

Answer (score 0):

If I set the joined entities first, it works.

```
    Person person = personDao.findById(rating.getPerson().getId());
    Job job = jobDao.findById(rating.getJob().getId());
    rating.setPerson(person);
    rating.setJob(job);
    rating = super.merge(rating);
```